# Why am i using result.getInt(2) / result.getInt(3) and result.getString(0)

Tags: java, sqlite

I am abit confused why in the RoutineRetrieved function I am using result.getInt(2) when assigning the ACTIVITYIMAGE and result.getInt(3) when assigning the SLOT.... while in the ColourChange function I am using result.getInt(0) when assigning the DAY.

I previously assumed I was pointing to the columns in my sqlite database. But now I am confused. Could someone explain what these numbers mean?

RoutineRetrieved function:

```
    private void routineRetrieved() {

    Cursor result = myDb.retrieveRoutine(currentDay);                                               

    if (result.getCount() == 0) {                                                                   
        // Do nothing

    } else {                                                                                        

        while (result.moveToNext()) {                                                               
            int ActivityImage = result.getInt(2);                                                   
            int Slot = result.getInt(3);                                                            
            ImageView emptySlot = (ImageView) findViewById(Slot);                                   
            emptySlot.setImageResource(ActivityImage);                                              
        }
    }
}
```

ColourChange function:

```
    private void colourChange() {
    Cursor result = myDb.checkColour();

    if (result.getCount() == 0) {                                                                   
        // Default colour remains

    } else {

        while (result.moveToNext()) {                                                               
            String day = result.getString(0);

            findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(day + "button", "id", getPackageName()))      
                    .setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSuccess));             
        }
    }
}
```

Database.java

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper

{
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "application.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 9;

// Table Name
public static final String RoutineTable = "Routines";

// Column Names
public static final String RoutineColumn1 = "DayOfWeek";
public static final String RoutineColumn2 = "Activity";
public static final String RoutineColumn3 = "Slot";

public Database(Context context)

{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `Routines` (`Routine` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,`DayOfWeek`   TEXT NOT NULL,`Activity`    INTEGER NOT NULL, `Slot` INTEGER NOT NULL);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)

{
    onCreate(db);
}


public Cursor retrieveRoutine(String selectedDay) {                                                  WHERE DayOfWeek equals selectedDay and store this as result.


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select * from " + RoutineTable + " WHERE DayOfWeek = '" + selectedDay + "'", null);

    return result;
}

public boolean insertRoutine(int activityImage, String selectedDay, int activitySlot) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(RoutineColumn1,selectedDay);                                                  
    contentValues.put(RoutineColumn2,activityImage);                                                
    contentValues.put(RoutineColumn3,activitySlot);                                                 
    long result = db.insert(RoutineTable, null, contentValues);                                     

    if(result == -1)                                                                                
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public Cursor checkColour() {                                                                      

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT DayOfWeek FROM " + RoutineTable + " GROUP BY DayOfWeek", null);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: it points to a [zero based columnIndex](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int)),  why  `String day = result.getString(0);` is pointing to the primary key `Routine` I can not tell (the app is probably implement on primary key), however I personally would not used columnIndex with a `SELECT *` statement, since it's enough that you change the database and your code will break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number parameter in the methods `getInt` and `getString` is index, starting by 0, of the column you want to get, *relatively to the query you've done*.

You have 2 different queries. In the method checkColour() you have the following query, which have only one field:

```
"SELECT DayOfWeek FROM " + RoutineTable + " GROUP BY DayOfWeek"
```

So, when you call

```
Cursor result = myDb.retrieveRoutine(currentDay);     
String fieldValue = result.getString(0);
```

`fieldValue` will have the value of the first field of the query, in this case `DayOfWeek`

The same in the other query, that is a `SELECT *` of the table Routines. In this case the index refers to the field position in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: So are you saying that with the CheckColour query it is 0 because it is only returning one field? While the RetrieveRoutine query is refering to the order set out in the CREATE TABLE statement at the top of the Database.java file - in other words DayOfWeek (first), Activity (second) and Slot (third).

Comment: Almost! Actually the first field is `Routine`, second is `DayOfWeek`, etc (: